# Make Go http.Response verbose all parameters

Tags: android, http, post, go

I am having a problem getting a parameter sent from android app into go application. I called r.FormValue(key) but it returned null. I want to find the way to check what are parameters available on Go side after the android app sent the post data to it. Is there any way to do this, getting all parameters without using keys?

Comment: Please share your Android request code

Comment: `request.ParseForm()` isn't working?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Request](https://golang.org/src/net/http/request.go?s=2057:8999#L64) structure in go has a `Form` field which is populated with request parameters after `ParseForm()` is called.

> Form contains the parsed form data, including both the URL field's
>   query parameters and the POST or PUT form data.This field is only
>   available after ParseForm is called. The HTTP client ignores Form and
>   uses Body instead.

You could try adding the following code after receiving a request:

```
func(w http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
    request.ParseForm()
    log.Printf("%v",request.Form)

    //....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If this is for debugging, you can use [DumpRequest](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httputil/#DumpRequest):

```
func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    dump, err := httputil.DumpRequest(r, true)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, fmt.Sprint(err), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
    log.Printf("%s", dump)
}
```